# I'm stuck with the following "error java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because "browserName" is null"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I can't identify any issue with the code, can someone help me

```
package com.ai.qa.base;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;

import com.ai.qa.utils.TestUtil;

public class TestBase {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties prop;

    public TestBase() {
        
        try {
            prop = new Properties();
            FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream("/AIRegressionTest/src/main/java/com/ai/qa/config/config.properties");
            prop.load(ip);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        
    }
    
}
         public static void initialization() {
             
             String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");
            
            if(browserName.equals("chrome")){
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\eclipse-workspace\\AIRegressionTest\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe"); 
                driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
            }
            else if(browserName.equals("FF")){
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\AIRegressionTest\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");  
                driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
            }

            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtil.IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            
            driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
             
             
             
    
         }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest debugging with a breakpoint on the line where you get the browser property. That will give you more information - you can inspect the contents of `prop`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check

```
String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");
```

- is there really "browser" property  in your **prop**
- is the name of your property correct - is it really "browser"